# SOSTOOLS in MATLAB: findbound gives wrong output

Tags: optimization, matlab, math-software, sums-of-squares

Here is the MATLAB code that uses SOSTOOLS toolbox:

```
clear;
syms a12 a13 C;
deg = 6;
vartable = [a12, a13, C];
prog = sosprogram(vartable);
solver_opt.solver = 'mosek';
[sol_C, vars, xopt] = findbound(C,[0],[-1 -54*a12^2 - 81*a12^4 - 54*a13^2 - 486*a12^2*a13^2 - 81*a13^4 + C*(1 + 6*a12^2 + a12^4 + 6*a13^2 + 6*a12^2*a13^2 + a13^4)],deg,solver_opt);
```

Output says:

```
No lower bound could be computed. Unbounded below or infeasible?
```

Whereas the Mathematica code:

```
Minimize[{c, -1 - 54*a12^2 - 81*a12^4 - 54*a13^2 - 486*a12^2*a13^2 - 
    81*a13^4 + 
    c*(1 + 6*a12^2 + a12^4 + 6*a13^2 + 6*a12^2*a13^2 + a13^4) == 
   0}, {a12, a13, c}]
```

gives the expected (correct) output:

```
{1, {a12 -> 0, a13 -> 0, c -> 1}}
```

What went wrong in the MATLAB code?

Comment: Maybe post at https://github.com/oxfordcontrol/SOSTOOLS/issues ?

Comment: Done. [adding more characters to reach 15 chars]

Comment: @MathewsBoban I changed your code a little bit and it works: deg = 8; p = -1 -54*a12^2 - 81*a12^4 - 54*a13^2 - 486*a12^2*a13^2 - 81*a13^4 + C*(1 + 6*a12^2 + a12^4 + 6*a13^2 + 6*a12^2*a13^2 + a13^4); [sol_C, vars, xopt] = findbound(C,[],[p],deg,solver_opt);

Comment: @RiverLi: Thanks, that works. Do you determine the correct degree to give as input by increasing it until the point where sol_C doesn't change with further increase in deg?

Comment: @MathewsBoban I used deg=8 and stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sum-of-squares approach tries to compute a lower bound (and in lucky cases where the bound is tight it might be possible to recover a solution). Here, it looks like the relaxation simply is bad due to too low degree multiplier (or there is a bug in your code, see below)

The code has a suspicious space as you are creating a vector of size 1x2 when you define the equalities

```
[-1 -54*a12^2 - 81
```

That is probably supposed to be

```
[-1 - 54*a12^2 - 81
```

Comment: That is a surprising and strange behaviour! `x = [-1 - 5 -6]` is a 1*2 vector while `y=[-1 -5 -6]` is a 1*3 vector.

Comment: No, it is entirely expected and follows MATLAB syntax and distinction between unitary - (and +) vs binary operator, and spacing rules.